# Compare similarity of two NSStrings

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring, compare

I would like to compare two `NSString`s. If the user types "Stonehhengge", should get a "border on answer"="almost equals", because the right answer is: "Stonhenge".

I would like a percentage of how much one string equals another. If "Stonhenge" is 9 letters, and the typed text contain 8 letters from "Stonhenge", but it's not equal to "Stonhenge", for example: "Stonehange" is not equal to "Stonhenge", but it's near - I'd like to know how near a match the strings are.

I only know `isEqual:`. If you type "Stonehenge", you match and will get the right symbol. If text field's text is not equal, you do not get a match and get the wrong symbol.

Comment: you need to look up fuzzy logic string matching, or string matching heuristics... I don't think there is anything automatic.

Comment: @incmiko I edited your question to make it clearer what you're asking, if you think I misrepresented something please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**
What you want is to compute [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

You may want to check out this question [Calculate number of differences between two NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397348/calculate-number-of-differences-between-two-nsstrings)

Comment: they want a "almost equals" it looks like

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the question then, can you refine it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I like this library, StringScore https://github.com/thetron/StringScore

It gives you these useful methods:

```
- (CGFloat) scoreAgainst:(NSString *)otherString;

- (CGFloat) scoreAgainst:(NSString *)otherString fuzziness:(NSNumber *)fuzziness;

- (CGFloat) scoreAgainst:(NSString *)otherString fuzziness:(NSNumber *)fuzziness options:(NSStringScoreOption)options;
```