# Comparing NSString with NSString return the match percent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I want a method to just pass two strings into, and have it return me the percentage difference between them.

Example:

String1 ---------- String2 --------- Precentage

"Test" ------------ "Texf" ------------ 50%

"Test1" ---------- "Test3" ----------- 80%

"Test3" ------------ "3" --------------- 20%

"Test" ----------- "Tesz" ------------ 75%

"Te3" -------------- "T" -------------- 33%

Comment: See also [Calculate number of differences between two NSStrings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397348) and [Check if two NSStrings are similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12984442).